# What happens to gas molecules after ionization?

Tags: energy, electricity, physical-chemistry, potential-energy, ionization-energy

I know that gas molecules conduct electricity after they get ionized but what will happen if we keep increasing the voltage even after ionization?  Will it explode? If it will then how much energy will be released? Assume I have neon gas in Crookes tube.

Answer (score 1):

Neon is not molecular, it is atomic.  A gas discharge has negative resistance not ohmic resistance. If you do not have a ballast you will blow your power supply.

Binding energy is negative. If you juice the plasma harder and harder, you will further ionize the atom and see more and more energetic parts of its emission spectra.  The last step is a hydrogen-like atom.  You can then play with Lamb shift.

Explode a thin wire with a switched large capacitor.  Balance inductance and echo for a good time.  The resulting plasma is used as a detonator.  If you want to do a Z-pinch, yer gonna need a bigger capacitor,

http://www.capturedlightning.com/frames/shrinkergallery.html 
or

[image]

Comment: I believe neon can be described as a [monatomic molecule](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803100205237).

Comment: Sounds interesting, but I think more detail is needed.